# Is there any way of getting mutual friends in OpenGraph v2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to get the mutual friends of 2 facebook users in OpenGraph v2.0? How about if they are both users of my app?

UPDATE:
Based on my research, you can get only mutual friends that are USING your app using the mutual_friends user context api
There is no way to get ALL mutual friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mutual friends in v2.0 you should use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_friends

Comment: Just to reiterate UPDATE: Based on my research, you can get only mutual friends that are USING your app using the mutual_friends user context api There is no way to get ALL mutual friends
.. Is there a work around for that

Comment: No that is by design. You can get the number of mutual friends

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the following API endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{friend_id}/friends
```

Depending on privacy settings for the user, you will see mutual friends of both users. e.g.:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Jane Smith", 
      "id": "xxxxxx"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "John Smith", 
      "id": "yyyyyy"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Joe Blogs", 
      "id": "zzzzzz"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: This request will also only return users who used the app: "This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request." Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends